# Out of memory errors when executing Jest on Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, jestjs

I'm trying to execute Jest on Ubuntu 14.04.02, in a virtual machine with 4gb of RAM.  node version 0.12.2, npm 2.0.0-alpha-5

free shows me:

```
              total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          3.8G       199M       3.6G       976K       1.1M        18M
```

When I run npm test, I keep getting a variety of out of memory errors:

```
Error: FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - process out of memory

FATAL ERROR: Committing semi space failed. Allocation failed - process out of memory

# Fatal error in ../deps/v8/src/heap/store-buffer.cc, line 132
# CHECK(old_virtual_memory_->Commit(reinterpret_cast<void*>(old_limit_), grow * kPointerSize, false)) failed
```

Any idea what the minimum memory requirement is...or if I have misconfiguration something that is leading to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out downgrading to node version 0.10.32, installed via npm, healed the issue.